# Null collection on OpenJPA relation mapping when used in Spring context

Tags: java, spring, jpa, one-to-many, openjpa

I have the following 2 entities:

```
@Entity
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer iduser;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Byte enabled;
    private Set<Token> tokens = new HashSet<>(0);

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String email, String password, Byte enabled/*, Set groupRights*/, Set tokens) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.tokens = tokens;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "iduser", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getIduser() {
        return this.iduser;
    }

    public void setIduser(Integer iduser) {
        this.iduser = iduser;
    }

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true, length = 45)
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name = "password", length = 60)
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    public Byte getEnabled() {
        return this.enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(Byte enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    public Set<Token> getTokens() {
        return this.tokens;
    }

    public void setTokens(Set<Token> tokens) {
        this.tokens = tokens;
    }

}

@Entity
public class Token implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String idtoken;
    private User user;
    private Date tokenTtl;
    private String ipLock;

    public Token() {
    }

    public Token(String idtoken) {
        this.idtoken = idtoken;
    }

    public Token(String idtoken, User user, Date tokenTtl, String ipLock) {
        this.idtoken = idtoken;
        this.user = user;
        this.tokenTtl = tokenTtl;
        this.ipLock = ipLock;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idtoken", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 36)
    public String getIdtoken() {
        return this.idtoken;
    }

    public void setIdtoken(String idtoken) {
        this.idtoken = idtoken;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "token_ttl", length = 19)
    public Date getTokenTtl() {
        return this.tokenTtl;
    }

    public void setTokenTtl(Date tokenTtl) {
        this.tokenTtl = tokenTtl;
    }

    @Column(name = "ip_lock", length = 45)
    public String getIpLock() {
        return this.ipLock;
    }

    public void setIpLock(String ipLock) {
        this.ipLock = ipLock;
    }

}
```

the problem is that when I select a user using this JPA-QL: `select u from User u`, I get a null `Set` related to `Token`s, even though there are associated tokens for this user.
This problem arises only when I get the JPA context (`EntityManager`) in a Spring 4 context. If I'm doing a test, creating the `EntityManager` directly (using this: `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("unit-name");`), this issue is not present.

Can anybody tell me what's the cause of my issue?

Comment: Did you try with cascade=CascadeType.ALL in Token entity for @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use in this way

```
 private Set<Token> tokens = new HashSet<Token>(0);
```

Create the Getter Setter accordingley

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    public Set<Token> getTokens() {
        return this.tokens;
    }

    public void setTokens(Set<Token>tokens) {
        this.tokens = tokens;
    }
```

Comment: It was just a tag display problem. I had already this in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to a bug from OpenJPA.
When in OpenJPA you create a bidirectional `@OneToMany` relationship  with `FetchType.EAGER` fetch type, the bug comes up by not being able to create this relation. The bug is fixed in some versions. Seems to affect versions 2.1.0, 2.2.2, 2.3.0 and 2.4.0.

References:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-2505

[Spring Data JPA OneToMany and ManyToOne give me JpaSystemException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761598/spring-data-jpa-onetomany-and-manytoone-give-me-jpasystemexception#answer-25239726)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Magnilex Thanks. Hope now it's better.